# PDF of $Y=\frac{8}{X^3}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, transformation, density-function

Consider the random variable X with probability density function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
 \frac{24}{x^4}; & \text{ if, } x>2 \\
 0; & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$ Find the probability density function of $Y=\frac{8}{X^3}$.

I tried using the formula $$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \vert\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g^{-1}(y)\vert.$$

where

$Y=g(x)=\frac{8}{x^3}$,

$g^{-1}(Y)=\frac{2}{y^\frac{1}{3}}$

but it ended up as $f_Y(y)=$$\frac{y^\frac{4}{3}}{|y\frac{4}{3}|}$

Can anyone tell me where it's gone wrong?

2nd attempt:
$P(Y \leq y) = P(\frac{8}{X^3} \leq y) = P(X \geq \frac{2}{y^\frac{1}{3}})$ = $1$- $P(X \leq \frac{2}{y^\frac{1}{3}})$ = $\frac{8}{y}$ using the integral on $f(x)$ over $2$ to $\frac{8}{y\frac{1}{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct for $0<y<1$. There is no need for absolute value so the density is $1$. Note that $X>2$ implies that $\frac 8 {X^{3}} \in (0,1)$ so $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

In your second method $P(Y \leq y)=P(X \geq  2 y^{-1/3})=\int_{ 2 y^{-1/3}}^{\infty} \frac {24}{x^{4}}dx=y$ if $y$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Hi, but I got a different answer if I did the integral method. Do you mind checking my workings?

Comment: @Car You did not integrate properly; I have edited my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain more why it's incorrect?

Comment: @Car You wrote $P(X \geq t)=1-P(X \geq t)$! That is the first mistake. Secondly, $P(X<t)=\int_2^{x} f(t)dt=8(\frac 1 8-\frac 1 {x^{3}})=1-\frac 8 {x^{3}}$. When you take $t=\frac 2 {y^{1/3}}$ in this you get $P(X<t)=1-y$ so we finally get $P(Y \leq y)=y$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. So does that mean Y~Uniform[0,1]?

Comment: @Car Yes, $Y$ is $unf [0,1]$

Comment: What does it mean if $P(Y≤y)=y$? I do understnad why it becomes uniform with my 1st method, but not with the integration method.

Comment: $P(Y \leq y)=y$ implies the density function is $1$. Differentiate $P(Y \leq y)$ w.r.t $y$ to get the density. @Car

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I might suggest writing $y^{-1/3}$ for visual clarity; the fraction in the integral bounds in particular is a bit unsightly. (The math itself is correct, of course.)

Comment: @Math1000 Done!